# Hodge Laplacian in local coordinates

Tags: elliptic-pde, differential-forms

On a Riemannian Manifold $M^n$, the Hodge Laplacian is defined on k-forms by $\Delta\omega=\operatorname{d}\operatorname{d}^*\omega+\operatorname{d}^*\operatorname{d}\omega$. For 0-forms, e.i. smooth functions, one can easily see that w.r.t. some local coordinates with inverse metric tensor $g^{ij}$ it holds:$$\Delta\omega=-\partial_j(g^{ij}\partial_i\omega)$$ This can be used to apply results of 1-dimensional elliptic regularity to $\Delta$. My goal is to understand elliptic regularity on all k-forms, $\Delta:\Omega^k(M)\rightarrow\Omega^k(M)$. My question is: How does the term of highest order (2nd order in derivatives) look like in a local trivialisation of k-forms? (e.g. $\omega=\sum_{I=(i_1,...,i_k)\\0≤i_1≤...≤i_k≤n}\omega_I \operatorname{d}x^{i_{1}}\wedge...\wedge\operatorname{d}x^{i_{k}}$ or alternatively using some local orthogonal frames).

Is it true or wrong that its highest order is diagonal?$$(\Delta\omega)_I=A^{I,ij}\partial_i\partial_j\omega_I+\sum_JB^{I,J,i}\partial_i\omega_J+\sum_J C^{I,J}\omega_J$$
Is it maybe even true that the $A^{I,ij}=-g^{ij}$ as in the k=0 case?

Comment: By hand, I could also veryfy all assertions for k=1

Comment: I think I proofed everything now, but my proof involves very shady business with the metric tensor.

Comment: Very good question. Actually I have been thinking about it recently since I need it in my research.

Comment: If there is interest, I will post the proof, but these days I am too busy.

Comment: Note that, if all you want is the top order term, then you can ignore all terms involving the derivatives of the metric tensor (equivalently, the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives). You can also do the calculation at a single point and assume that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ at that point. This simplifies the calculations.

Answer (score 4):

**Your formula is true.**

The Weitzenböck formula states that the Hodge Laplacian on $k$-forms satisfies
$$
\Delta\omega=(d\delta+\delta d)\omega=\nabla^*\nabla\omega +\operatorname{Ric}(\omega),
$$
where $\nabla^*\nabla$ is the Bochner Laplacian. For a proof, see Theorem 9.4.1 in:

**P. Petersen,** *Riemannian geometry.* Third edition. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 171. Springer, Cham, 2016.

Finally, the Bochner Laplacian in suitable local coordinates can be represented as 
$$
\nabla^*\nabla=-\sum_{k,j} \big\{\ g^{kj}\nabla_k\nabla_j+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_{x^k}\big(\sqrt{|g|}g^{kj}\big)\cdot\nabla_j\ \big\}.
$$
This is proved in Example 10.1.32 in

**L. I. Nicolaescu**, *Lectures on Geometry of Manifolds*.

Beautiful Nicolaescu's lectures are [freely available on his homepage](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Note that the curvature term in the Weitzenböck formula is only the Ricci curvature when $\omega$ is a $1$-form.  In general it involves the Riemannian curvature tensor.  However, it always acts on $\omega$ as a zeroth-order operator, so this has no effect on the principal symbol.